# How to fix oracle TNS - Connection timed out error when connecting to database remotely?

Tags: linux, database, oracle

I am trying to connect to oracle database hosted on Linux server remotely from my windows machine and getting error ORA-12170: TNS: Connect Timeout. I've already checked the following:

1. listener.ora configuration and it's status.
2. tnsnames.ora naming parameters.
3. firewall is listening on the IP and the default port 1521

Comment: setup [TNS Tracing](http://www.oracledistilled.com/oracle-database/troubleshooting/setting-up-oracle-net-services-tracing-on-the-client-and-server/) on your client.

Answer (score 0):

If there is no firewall between the client and the target database then you should not normally need to adjust the timeout.  You can try adjusting the sqlnet parameters mentioned in the error message: *Action: If the error occurred because of a slow network or system,
// reconfigure one or all of the parameters SQLNET.INBOUND_CONNECT_TIMEOUT,
// SQLNET.SEND_TIMEOUT, SQLNET.RECV_TIMEOUT in sqlnet.ora to larger values.
- -
However, I think you should ask your network team to trace your connection attempt especially if after increasing the timeout you still get the error. The full Oracle version in use and the platforms (client and target) may be important.